# how to destroy cookie after 1 minute in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies, cakephp-3.x

I am new in cakephp 3.0. i have successfull created a cookie but i want to destroy that cookie after one minute. i have done so far:-

```
public function register_cookie(){
    $data = "Hello world!";
    $this->Cookie->write('dataFetch', $data, true, time() + (60 * 1));
}
public function getcookie() {
        $cookiedata = $this->Cookie->read('dataFetch');
        echo $cookiedata;
}
```

but when i come after one minute in **getCookie** function it still prints   i.e. "Hello World"
i want after one minute cookie is expired.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The code seems right to me. So it can be the logical error. Can you provide the code where you call this functions. It can be because you are writing cookie again before getting it.

Comment: i have provided these names of my own

Comment: From where you have called `register_cookie` and `getcookie` functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cakephp 3.x as the document says you can have these paramenters

[CookieComponent::write(mixed $key, mixed $value = null)](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/cookie.html#Cake%5CController%5CComponent%5CCookieComponent::write)

But in cakephp 2.x it use to take these parameters

[CookieComponent::write(mixed $key, mixed $value = null, boolean $encrypt = true, mixed $expires = null)](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html#CookieComponent::write)

To set expiry time you have to set the configuration like this

```
$this->Cookie->config([
    'expires' => '+10 days',
]);
```

So you code will be like this

```
public function register_cookie(){
    $this->Cookie->config([
        'expires' => '+1 minute',
    ]);
    $this->Cookie->configKey('dataFetch', 'encryption', false);
    $data = "Hello world!";
    $this->Cookie->write('dataFetch', $data);
}
```

Comment: but when i read the cookie data in between one minute it's not print data in getCookie function

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check if the cookie expiration date was set correctly. For example, in Chrome (after inspect element triggers the console bar), go to Application\Storage\Cookies\Localhost and check the cookie.

In cakephp you can delete a cookie with

```
$this->Cookie->delete('bar');
```

Also you can destroy a cookie by setting the expiration date into the past with time()-1

Comment: how to do that in getcookie function

Comment: You code is correct... If it shows 2017-03-10 it means that it will expire on 10th of March. Check if your clock settings are correct. It should be 10th February your current time + 60 seconds.